# How to modify struct sk_buff

Tags: linux-kernel, vpn

I have to write a vpn module. First of all, I have wrote a kernel module that modifies all the incoming and outgoing TCP packets. It uses netfilter hooks. For the incoming packets, I have modified the bytes between `(struct sk_buff)->data` and `(struct sk_buff)->tail` pointers by incrementing them by one. For the outgoing packets, I have modified the bytes between `(struct sk_buff)->data` and `(struct sk_buff)->tail` pointers by decrementing them by one.

However, I tried to establish a TCP connection between localhost and localhost (by means of netcat) and I had not succeeded. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Need I modify some other fields from the struct `sk_buff` structure?

---

Is it possible to implement my simple vpn module only from kernel space?(thus without using special libraies such as libnetfilter_queue)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this without using libnetfilter.  But given the limited information that you've provided about your project it's hard to give a good recommendation as to how to go about fixing your issue.   Here's some references that should help.

1) I would recommend you take a look at the [TUN/TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) interface driver APIs.  This will allow you to implement your code in application space rather than kernel.   See [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) for a great example of this type of VPN.

If you're interested in doing more advanced kernel space hooking...
2) Check this article out on hooking into netfilter [netfilter kernel hooks](http://kd7yhr.org/bushbo/misc/phrack/phrack61/p61-0x0d_Hacking_the_Linux_Kernel_Network_Stack.txt)

Comment: netfilter kernel hooks link is broken